# select datatable list in spotfire

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

I am trying to put filter on datatable name in dropdown, for which i need list of datatable in my analysis page. How to list down all datatables name so that i can select them in drop down and then show data specific to data table in tabular view.

```
import Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataTable
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import *

dataTable = Document.Data.Tables['dataTableName']

for column in dataTable.Columns:
    print column
```

Above gives me column for the data table name i supply, but what i need is list of datatables and then put them into dropdown filter to select specific data table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import *

for x in Document.Data.Tables:
    print x.Name
```

You can then assign the values that get kicked out of the loop to a document property, and use that in a drop down/to set another document property if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need to import any libraries...

```
for dtable in Document.Data.Tables:
    print dtable.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can feel free to print as you like, this is the base code that you will require to map columns for all tables.

```
for tables in Document.Data.Tables:
tablename = tables.Name
for column in DataTable.Columns:
    externalname = column.Properties["ExternalName"]
    internalname = column.Name
```